# Node: 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup' indices[31,197] = 159947 is not in [0, 159943)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, neural-network

here's my neural network:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(max_len, )))
model.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size,  output_dim = embd_dim, input_length = max_len, weights = [final_embeddings], trainable=False))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
```

here's how the word embeddings were generated:

```py
vocab_size = 159943

all_embd = np.stack(embd_values)
embd_mean, embd_std = all_embd.mean(), all_embd.std()
final_embeddings = np.random.normal(embd_mean, embd_std, (vocab_size, embd_dim))
for word , i in tok.word_index.items():
    word_embedding = word_vec_dict.get(word)
    if word_embedding is not None:
        final_embeddings[i] = word_embedding

len(final_embeddings)--> 159943
```

here's the test data size->153164

```py
tok = Tokenizer()
tok.fit_on_texts(test['comment_text_transformed'])
encd_reviews_test = tok.texts_to_sequences(test['comment_text_transformed'])
```

here's the predict function

```py
y_pred_test = model.predict([pad_reviews_test], 1024)
```

and now here is the error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[121], line 1
----> 1 y_pred_test = model.predict([pad_reviews_test])

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):

Node: 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup'
indices[31,197] = 159947 is not in [0, 159943)
     [[{{node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_26583]
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You told keras your vocabulary size is 159943, but you have a index that is larger than that (159947), which is not correct.

Comment: Yes and I don't know how to fix that because there is another fiel which contains the test data so how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: It cannot be dynamic, the vocabulary between test and train has to be exactly the same.

Comment: oh please tell how can i do that?

Comment: No problem. the error has been resolved. Just use tok.text_to_sequences method on the new df and not tok.word_index.